# get result of view using services from drupal 6

Tags: views, 6, services

I am using services 3 with drupal 6 to create node of story content type.
I have a cck field that contains email id of the user who has created the node.

I have a view that takes as argument an email id and returns all the nodes that have this email id in the cck field specified above.

All I want to do is, get the result of this view over rest call using services module as I am using this for mobile app.

I have tried using service views module, but its a dev version for drupal 6 and doesn't work for me.

Any solutions to this ?

Comment: Any hint on this ? I cant think that no one ever solved this.